# firebase_performance - Default FirebaseApp is not initialized - FlutterFire

Tags: flutter, firebase-performance

I have a flutter project with Android, iOS and Web platforms enabled, I'm using the following firebase plugins:

- firebase_performance: ^0.8.2+1
- firebase_database: ^9.0.20
- cloud_firestore: ^3.4.1
- firebase_core: ^1.20.0

All of them are added usgin FlutterFire. This is my main file:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  initializeDateFormatting('es');
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
.....
}
```

When i remove **firebase_perfomance** the app works fine, but when i add this plugin the app return the folliwing error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.testapp.test_performance. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

I haven't google-services.json beacause I understand that it is not necessary if I use **flutterfire**

Comment: Same issue here, firebase performance plugin does not work on Android if you do not add the configuration on the Android side (ie dependencies and the google-services.json file)

Answer (score 0):

I run into same problem today :(
It's weird that seems Firebase App won't auto initialized before the flutter startup, if you setup the firebase plugin with flutterfire cli. And no one mentioned this problem.

Solution:
You can follow the https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup to setup the google services plugin,the firebase service seems would initialized to get the performance monitor works in early stage of APP.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with `firebase_performance` package. I solved the issue by running the following commands again.

1. `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`
2. `flutterfire configure`